# why do I have to cast when assigning

Tags: java, oop, object, polymorphism

EarthquakeMarker is an abstract class that extends SimplePointMarker. OceanQuakeMarker extends EarthquakeMarker.

```
SimplePointMarker pm = new OceanQuakeMarker(feature);
EarthquakeMarker em = pm;
```

I read that this code wont compile because of the assignment of `em = pm`. However, `pm` has an "is-a" relationship with `em`, so I'm wondering why I have to cast it:

```
SimplePointMarker pm = new OceanQuakeMarker(feature);
EarthquakeMarker em = (EarthquakeMarker) pm;
```

Also, I'm wondering what happens to the functionality of `em` since it has been casted to the abstract parent class. Does it lose the functionality that the OceanQuakeMarker has?

Comment: Read this article and you will have a  good understanding than we can explain. It's all about upcasting and downcasting.
https://www.edureka.co/blog/upcasting-and-downcasting-in-java/

Comment: According to your description `OceanQuakeMarker` is-a `EarthquakeMarker` which is-a `SimplePointMarker`. However, you need `SimplePointMarker` to be `is-a` `EarthquakeMarker` in order to assign `em = pm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your explanation, given below is the hierarchy:

```
OceanQuakeMarker ▸ ⁨EarthquakeMarker ▸ ⁨SimplePointMarker
```

In the code given below, you are trying to assign a reference of `SimplePointMarker` to that of `EarthquakeMarker` which voilates the OOP principle. While a child class reference can be assigned to that of a parent class, the reverse is not true.

```
SimplePointMarker pm = new OceanQuakeMarker(feature);
EarthquakeMarker em = pm;
```

The code given below is correct because you have cast the parent class reference to the child class reference.

```
SimplePointMarker pm = new OceanQuakeMarker(feature);
EarthquakeMarker em = (EarthquakeMarker) pm;
```

The following code also will compile successfully for the same reason:

```
OceanQuakeMarker pm = new OceanQuakeMarker(feature);
EarthquakeMarker em = pm;
```

Comment: So I casted the variable `pm` of type `simplePointMarker` to an `earthQuakeMarker`. That means that I can assign `em = pm` because the compiler now sees them as having the same class. What happens at runtime? will `em` be seen as an oceanQuakeMarker? or does casting cause both the variable and the actual object to change?

Comment: `What happens at runtime? will em be seen as an oceanQuakeMarker?` - Correct; `em` will be referencing an instance of `OceanQuakeMarker` at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't know the type of the Object at compile time but it knows the type of the variable.

In case of

```
SimplePointMarker pm = new OceanQuakeMarker(feature);
EarthquakeMarker em = pm;
```

Java does only know that `pm` is a `SimplePointMarker` but the real type (`OceanQuakeMarker`) is unknown at compile time.

Theoretically, the object could be changed at any time and it wouldn't be a `EarthquakeMarker` any more.

As the real type is unknown at compile-time, it will be like

```
SimplePointMarker pm;//=something
EarthquakeMarker em = pm;
```

Therefore, you'll have to cast it because a `SimplePointMarker` is not always a `EarthquakeMarker`.

As the real type is only known at runtime, the type will also be tested at runtime.

If you cast an object to a type the object is not an instance of, a `ClassCastException` will be thrown.

Comment: Also, I believe that this will cause Java to throw a runtime error if the object that it finds *isn't* an `EarthquakeMarker` or one of its descendents.

Comment: Yes, a `ClassCastException`. I will add it.

Comment: To clarify, when casting `EarthquakeMarker em = (EarthquakeMarker) pm;` Does that mean em is now an EarthQuakeMarker variable that points to an actual OceanQuakeMarker object at runtime? Or does the casting change both the variable and the actual object?

Comment: Casting means using the object as an object of the casted type. For this, it already needs to be an object of that type.